# Loop all the imports and store it in array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Supposed I have a `__init__.py` that contains imports of Classes

```
#  src/classes

from .one_class import OneClass
from .two_class import TwoClass
from .three_class import ThreeClass
```

and I imported it all to a different file using

```
from src.classes import *

#  code here
```

Is it possible to loop all the imports and store it in an array?

Output could be: `[OneClass, TwoClass, ThreeClass]`

Any idea where can I start? I'm fairly new to python. Thanks

Comment: Don't do this: `from src.classes import *`. It is generally a bad practice. Instead, `import src.classes` then you can do something like `[x for x in vars(src.classes).values() if isinstance(attr, type)]`

Comment: Although, if you really need that, then you should do something like `class_list = [OneClass, TwoClass, ThreeClass]` in `src/classes/__init__.py`

Comment: regarding on the isinstance(attr, type) where can I get that params attr and type?

Comment: From the Zen of Python (`import this`): `Explicit is better than implicit.`

Comment: @Beginner https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance

Comment: I get it now thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: you can define `__all__` in `__init__.py` which contains all the classes in that file and use it

Comment: Yes, perhaps the one thing that isn't obvious, `type` is a class, the *class of all classes*, i.e. a "metaclass". All classes, e.g. `class Foo: pass` then `isinstance(Foo, type)` will be true. Same as built-in classes `isinstance(list, type)`

Comment: @sahasrara62 yes, although that should be strings containing the names.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via **`locals()`**:

```
from src.classes import *

src_imports = [name for name in locals() if not name.startswith('_')]
```

or my importing `classes` as a module:

```
from src import classes

src_imports = [getattr(name, classes) for name in dir(classes) 
               if not name.startswith('_')]
```

but as mentioned in the comments, this is bad practice.  It makes your code much harder to read and can lead to mysterious bugs.